# mutt No such file or directory

Tags: php, mutt

I am getting Can't stat filename No such file or directory when using mutt.

The csv file creates fine, my php mutt code is :

```
exec("export EMAIL=from_email && /bin/echo 'message' | /usr/bin/mutt -s 'subject' -a '$filename' -- 'email1@test.com email2@test.com'");
```

The files are created in the tmp directory. I tried putting the files in another directory but got can't attach file permission denied.

I am using version 1.5.21.

Also are multiple email addresses separated by a space?

Comment: What is the value of `$filename`?

Comment: Just /tmp/filename.csv

Comment: Does this command execute properly from the command line (pure `$ export EMAIL=from_email && /bin/echo 'message' | /usr/bin/mutt -s 'subject' -a '$filename' -- 'email1@test.com email2@test.com'`?)

Comment: I forgot that the file is stored on another server, so filename would be 'ip_address/tmp/filename.csv'. Still same error though

Comment: What about plain command-line execution?

Comment: It produces the same error

Comment: I have no clue whether `mutt` is able to deal with remotely hosted files. I would suggest as a hotfix you to chain `wget` like: `wget -0 $localfile $filename && /usr/bin/mutt -s 'subject' -a '$localfile' -- 'email1@test.com email2@test.com'`. If this works, it may be easily adopted to be called from `exec`.